# Handlebars: 2 sources 1 template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have one handlebars template but I want to include variables from two different sources in this template.

```
<script id="notification-menu-item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
```

I have tried to make both of the sources go to the same template id. Both files have this:

```
var source                 = $("#notification-menu-item").html();
var template               = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

But only one of sources' variable come through to the template. Is there anyway to have one template get its `{{variables}}` from two different sources?

**Edit: The code**

This is the template:

```
<script id="notification-menu-item" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div id="navmenucontainer" class="container">
        <div id="navmenuv">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li>Topics</li>
              <li>Help</li>
              {{#if logged_user}}
                <li>Notifications</li>
                {{#if pro}}
                <li>My Data</li>
                {{/if}}
              {{/if}}
              </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

`pro` comes from one .js file and `logged_user` comes from a separate .js file. Is there a way for both of these variable to be used in the same template?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "only one of sources' variables come through"? I don't see in the code you included in your question where you ever render your template. I only see the `Handlebars.compile`.

Comment: You're compiling only one template, and not invoking it, i.e. `template(params)`. Need more clarification on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @SeanGlover @StevenSchobert: added in the template code to make it more clear what I am doing. In one JS file I have `var html = template({logged_user: logged_user}); $('body').prepend(html);` and in the other I have `var html = template({pro: pro});
      $('body').prepend(html);`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more the necessity of your having two js files?

Comment: @SeanGlover - I am using Discourse (forum builder created by Jeff Atwood) and building plugins for it. Without going into too much detail about Discourse, essentially I have two plugins (two JS files) trying to change one handlebars template.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to centralize the rendering of the template into one function somehow if you want to composite the data before passing it into the `Handlebars.compile()` function. I guess you're going to have to somehow guarantee the order in which these "plugin" js files call this new function. Otherwise it turns into something really janky like this:

Example:

`Class1.js`

```
var source = $("#notification-menu-item").html();
var html = Notification.renderNotification(source, logged_user, undefined);
if (typeof html !== 'undefined') {
   $('body').prepend(html);
}
```

`Class2.js`

```
var source = $("#notification-menu-item").html();
var html = Notification.renderNotification(source, undefined, pro);
if (typeof html !== 'undefined') {
   $('body').prepend(html);
}
```

`Notification.js`

```
window.Notification = function() {
   var logged_user = undefined;
   var pro = undefined;
   return {
      renderNotification: function(source, user, isPro) {
         if (typeof user !== 'undefined') {
            logged_user = user;
         }

         if (typeof pro !== 'undefined') {
            pro = isPro;
         }

         if(typeof logged_user !== 'undefined' 
            && typeof pro !== 'undefined') {
               var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
               var html = template({logged_user: logged_user, pro: pro});
               return html;
         }
      }
}
```

Obviously this is not elegant and far from maintainable. Without getting into the specifics of how Discourse works though, I'm not sure what to tell you. At render time of the template, a full object containing all the relevant data should be passed. Subsequent calls to `Handlebars.compile()` would require the full set of data. Maybe should consider finding a way to split these templates up and render them into separate page elements asynchronously, or look into [Partials](http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html)

Disclaimer: I'm not an expert on JS or logicless templates.